# Extract and add a link from pdf object in a div with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, object

I have a bunch of PDFs embedded in a webpage, and I would like to either prepend or append a download link for each one. For instance:

```
<div>
  <object data="files/schedule.pdf" width="99%" height="800"></object>
<div class="link">
  Download Link: <a href="files/schedule.pdf">schedule.pdf</a>
</div>
```

This way the PDF will load in the page, but if for whatever reason the user has a plugin or addon disabled there will still be a link where they can download the document.

Is there a way to programmatically fill "link" class divs with the preceeding link?

(PDF display)

"Download Link: < a href="+ filepath +" > + filename + < /a >"

Would it be better to go about it the other way? As in, have the link hard coded, but then populate the object data with the file path? Basically I am looking to save having to put the file path in twice for every object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code identifies all `<object>` tags on the page, retrieves the uri from the `data=` attribute and creates a download link `<div>` immediately after the object tag. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/sUrD5/). (requires jQuery library)

```
$(function(e) {
    var filename_re = /[^\/]+\.pdf$/;
    $('object').each(function(index) {
        var uri = $(this).attr('data');
        var filename = filename_re.exec(uri);
        $(this).after('<div class="link">Download Link: <a href="'+uri+'">'+filename+'</a></div>');
    }); 
});
```

Plain Javascript version (no jQuery required). See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tppiotrowski/5Mhyy/):

```
var filename_re = /[^\/]+\.pdf$/;
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
    var uri = obj[i].data;
    var filename = filename_re.exec(uri);
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = 'Download Link: <a href="'+uri+'">'+filename+'</a>';
    obj[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div, obj[i].nextSibling);
}​
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I was using jQuery anyway, so integrated immediately. Thanks!

Comment: Could this be modified to display different text if there was a webpage in the object instead of a pdf? For instance, to just have a link that says "Link" instead of the filename?

Comment: so you want a Download Link: filename if the url ends in .pdf and just a Link if it ends in something else (.html for example)?